# Paste dataframe columns into a pre-formatted string

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
                                                  ~topic,   ~substance,
                                  "Pregnancy, High-Risk",  "Krill oil",
        "Pregnancy Complications/ prevention & control*", "Fish oils*",
                "Premature Birth/ prevention & control*",    "Omega 3")
```

I would like to combine each element of the columns into a preformatted string representing a query to be used in PubMed (a database for scientific literature).

The query has a combination of OR and AND and parentheses, in this format:

```
query <- "((Topic 1) OR (Topic 2) OR (Topic 3)) AND ((Substance 1) OR (Substance 2) OR (Substance 3))"
```

aka:

```
(
(Pregnancy, High-Risk)
OR
(Pregnancy Complications/ prevention & control*)
OR
(Premature Birth/ prevention & control*)
)
AND
(
(Krill oil)
OR
(Fish oils*)
OR
(Omega 3)
)
```

How can I achieve this in a tidy-verse oriented way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this in base R itself using `paste`.

```
paste(sapply(df, function(x) 
      paste("(", paste("(", x, ")", collapse = " OR"), ")")), collapse = " AND ")

#"( ( Pregnancy, High-Risk ) OR( Pregnancy Complications/ prevention & control* ) 
#        OR( Premature Birth/ prevention & control* ) ) AND
#     ( ( Krill oil ) OR( Fish oils* ) OR( Omega 3 ) )"
```

Used `sapply` if you have multiple columns that you need to join. If you really need it you can definitely translate this using `stringr::str_c`.